# Prove the following using proportions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Please tell, if anything wrong has been done by me. The question is from : "HIGHER ALGEBRA" by Hall and Knight. [image]

Comment: Unreadable. Spend a minimum effort retranscripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{b}{c}=\frac{c}{d}=\frac{1}{\lambda}$$

So, $$b=\lambda a\tag{1}$$

$$c=\lambda b$$

From $(1)$, we have $$c=\lambda^2a\tag{2}$$

$$d=\lambda c$$

From $(2)$, we have $$d=\lambda^3a\tag{3}$$

$$\text{L.H.S }=(a^2+b^2+c^2)(b^2+c^2+d^2)$$

Using $(1),(2)$ and $(3)$ we get

$$\begin{align}\text{L.H.S }=(a^2+\lambda^2a^2+\lambda^4a^2)(\lambda^2a^2+\lambda^4a^2+\lambda^6a^2)\\
=[a^2(1+\lambda^2+\lambda^4)][a^2 \lambda^2(1+\lambda^2+\lambda^4)]\\
=\color{blue}{a^4\lambda^2(1+\lambda^2+\lambda^4)^2}\\
\end{align}$$

$$\text{R.H.S }=(ab+bc+cd)^2$$

Using $(1),(2)$ and $(3)$, we get

$$\begin{align}\text{R.H.S }=\left[(a \cdot \lambda a)+(\lambda a \cdot \lambda^2 a)+(\lambda^2 a \cdot \lambda^3 a)\right]^2\\
=\left[( a^2\lambda)(1+\lambda^2+\lambda^4)\right]^2\\
=\color{blue}{a^4\lambda^2(1+\lambda^2+\lambda^4)^2}\\
\end{align}$$

So, we get $$\text{L.H.S }=\text{R.H.S }$$

Comment: How is b=(lambda)*a ?

Comment: @user115962 I have made the necessary edits.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac ab = \frac bc = \frac cd = \lambda$ is great.

Now I would put this to use right away...

e.g. 
$a = \lambda b, b = \lambda c, c= \lambda d\\
(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)  = \lambda^2 (b^2 + c^2 + d^2)$

or
$(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)  = (\lambda^4 + \lambda^2 + 1) c^2$

Instead it looks like you have multiplied out the expressions with the intention of tackling the lambdas later, and in so doing you did not multiply out all of the terms

$(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)(b^2 + c^2 + d^2) = a^2 b^2 + a^2 c^2 + a^2 d^2 + b^4 + b^2 c^2 + b^2 d^2 + c^2 b^2 + c^4 + c^2 d^2\\
(ab + bc + cd)^2 = a^2b^2 + b^2c^2 + c^2d^2 + 2ab^2c + 2abcd+2bc^2 d$

Setting these two equal to one another and canceling like terms:

$a^2 c^2 + a^2 d^2 + b^4 + b^2 d^2 + b^2 c^2 + c^4 = 2ab^2c + 2abcd+2bc^2 d$

And then you could proceed as you had above.  Again, I don't think that this is the easiest way, but, it is the direction you had started.

The value of $\lambda$ is ultimately irrelevant.  All you need to do is show that what is on the left equals what is on the right.